# Python __str__ within classes confusion

Tags: python

I've seen the term `__str__` used a lot within classes in Python. I've tried to look up what it means and its functions but many websites teach it in relation to the Java function `toString` or `__repr__`. As I don't come from a Java background, its hard for me to learn it that way. I've also seen people compare it to the function `str()` but I don't know how accurate that is or in what ways.

Could someone explain it to me in simple terms? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about `__str__` in general or about the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`?

Answer (score 1):

When Python needs to convert a class instance to a string, it calls its `__str__()` method. If it doesn't have `__str__()` it falls back on `__repr__()`. If the class doesn't define either of these methods, it will normally inherit them from the `object` base class, which returns a string like `<className object at 0x1234>`

This is used by the `str()` function, as well as formatting methods like `str.format()`, the string `%` operator, and f-strings. So defining the `__str__()` method allows you to customize how objects in your class are displayed in messages.

Analogously, the `repr()` function calls the `__repr__()` method. This method is generally intended to return a string containing a representation more appropriate for debugging and/or parsing, rather than for end user display.

Answer (score 0):

The [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) magic method defines the string representation of an object.

Here is an example for a very boring class `A`:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> str(A())
'<__main__.A object at 0x7fe249b93ac8>'
```

This is the default. It uses the built-in `__str__` method inherited from `object`. For our class `B`, we're looking for a more individual approach:

```
>>> class B:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "Something individual"
... 
>>> str(B())
'Something individual'
```

If you're looking for the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`, have a look here [Difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)